# bad accuracy with cross_val_score

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cross-validation

For machine learning classification, i use cross validation with 10 folds:

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
```

I split train/test datas:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3 )
```

For a classifier, 10 folds Accuracy mean is getted:

```
cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y=Y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4))
```

This give me an accuracy mean of 0,62.

To confirm accuracy value, i laucnh a prediction:

```
Y_pred_train = classifier.predict(X_train)

print(metrics.classification_report(Y_train, Y_pred_train))
```

I got:
        precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.92      0.96      0.94      2523
       1       0.95      0.89      0.92      1923

accuracy                           0.93      4446
```

macro avg       0.93      0.93      0.93      4446
weighted avg       0.93      0.93      0.93      4446

This accuracy doesnt' match with this above.
How to explain it? 
Thanks a lot.
Théo

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are training the model on `X_train` and then run prediction on exactly same dataset:

```py
Y_pred_train = classifier.predict(X_train)
```

You are obviously getting an excellent score as the model could fit well to the training data. The point of machine learning to work on previously unseen data, i.e. generalise between what was known at training time. To fix the issue, simply run the prediction and report on test data:

```py
Y_pred_test = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(metrics.classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you.
In fact i want to compare accuracy value getted with cross_val_score() and .predict() function.
For me, on the same train dataset, both should be identical.

But accuracy value getted is not the same with cross_val_score() function and with  predict() classifier function.

Look i train cross_val_score() and predict() on the same train dataset.
Accuracy value for cross_val_score(, X_train, y=Y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4)) 
=> give me  0,62.

Accuracy value  for .predict(X_train) 
=> give me 0.92 (after i gridsearched best hyper parameters for my classifier .)

Could low accuracy value for cross_val_score be explained by default hyper parameters when i call 
cross_val_score(, X_train, y=Y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4))?

Thanks a lot.
Theo